# Swift: reason for two variables before ":"

Tags: function, methods, swift

Here's Apple's official Doc example:

```
class Counter {
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount:Int, numberOfTimes times:Int){
        count += amount * times
    }
}

var counter = Counter()
counter.incrementBy(2, numberOfTimes: 8)
```

Actually, what's the difference with the following codes:

```
class Counter {
    var count: Int = 0
    func incrementBy(amount:Int, numberOfTimes:Int){
        count += amount * numberOfTimes
    }
}

var counter = Counter()
counter.incrementBy(2, numberOfTimes: 8)
```

why `times` is put inside in the official Doc?
i'm new to programming, can someone explain the theory behind?
Thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberOfTimes` is the external parameter name/label, whereas `times` is the internal parameter name, used only inside the function. See [Function Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) for more information.